# What is the difference between creating list (followed by list assignment to dataframe) and using loc to update dataframe while iterating?

Tags: python, pandas

```
# importing pandas as pd
import pandas as pd

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': ['Umbrella', 'Matress', 'Badminton',
                'Shuttle', 'Sofa', 'Football'],
    'MRP': [1200, 1500, 1600, 352, 5000, 500],
    'Discount': [0, 10, 0, 10, 20, 40]
})

#Option 1
lst=[]
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    lst.append(somefn(row['MRP']))
df['newcol']=lst

#Option 2
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index,'newcol']=somefn(row['MRP'])

#Option 3 (this is chaining so won't update original df)
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    df[index].loc['newcol']=somefn(row['MRP'])
```

What is the difference between creating list/list assignment and using loc to update dataframe while iterating?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference is that when creating a list you have the overhead of converting the list to a series before assigning it to a data frame column. I think the most elegant way would be to use the `apply` method:

```py
# importing pandas as pd
import pandas as pd

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': ['Umbrella', 'Matress', 'Badminton',
                'Shuttle', 'Sofa', 'Football'],
    'MRP': [1200, 1500, 1600, 352, 5000, 500],
    'Discount': [0, 10, 0, 10, 20, 40]
})

#Option 4
df['newcol']=df['MRP'].apply(somefn)
```